# Sort by 2 custom fields. One field is sometimes empty

Tags: wordpress

I like to sort by 2 custom fields(AAA and BBB).  Sort by AAA first, then sort by BBB.  BBB is sometimes empty, but I like to catch all posts.

Here's my code.
Im making 2 arrays connected by 'or'. One array is AAA and BBB, and another array is AAA only.

```
'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'or',
    array(
      array(
      'key'=> 'AAA',
      ), 
      array(
      'key'=> 'BBB',
      ),                
      ),
    'key'=> 'AAA',
),

'orderby' => 'meta_value',
```

Above code does not show any error.  It shows posts who has value of both AAA and BBB.  Posts who has value AAA only are not shown.

I tried the below code too.  This code shows only posts with meta field AAA and BBB.

```
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'or',    
array(
array( 
'key'=> 'AAA',
),

array( 
'key'=> 'BBB',
),    
),
),

'orderby' => 'meta_value',
```

The following code shows posts with AAA and BBB, and sorted by AAA.  BBB is not sorted.

```
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'or',    

array( 
'key'=> 'color',
),

array( 
'key'=> 'species2',
),
),
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context?  What is the issue? Does the above code not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi.  Above code does not show any error.  It shows posts who has value of both AAA and BBB.  Posts who has value AAA only are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the second `'key'=> 'AAA',`?

```
'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'or',
  array(
    array(
      'key'=> 'AAA',
    ), 
    array(
      'key'=> 'BBB',
    ),                
  ),
),
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
```

Comment: Thank you Mikerojas.  I tried same and similar code like above, but it does not sort posts correctly.